# Centering main image with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, srcset

There are several centering issues with Bootstrap on SO but I didn't find my exact issue.

My site can be viewed at http://project.livestagingserver.com/test.html

Here is the code:

```css
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}

/********************************************
  h1
  h2
  h3
  .center
  p
  #footy
  #copy

*********************************************/
h1{
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h2{
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}
h3{
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.center{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
}

#footy{
    height: 40px;
    /*border: 1px solid red !important;*/
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

/*Main Styles*/
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 945px;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}

#logo {
    padding: 10px;
}

#name {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.featured {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#titles {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

#urls {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

#urls a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#mainImage{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#footy {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 945px;
}

#copy{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100' rel='stylesheet'>

    <title>Framework Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div id="header" class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="logo" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img src="img/denvercoderlogo.png" alt="Denver Coder Logo with Denver Skyline and Mountains"/>
            </div>
            <div id="name" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><h1>Timothy Myers</h1>

                <h3>Denver COder</h3></div>
        </div> <!-- Header -->


    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">


        <picture class="col-xs-12 center">
            <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="img/mainImageSet/mainImage.jpg">
            <img src="img/mainImageSet/mainImageMedium.jpg" alt="Desk with laptop and some supplies"/>
        </picture>


    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="features">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="featured">Featured Work</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Luke For Prez</h2>
            <img class="center" src="img/darthImageSet/darthnevets.png" alt="Stylized Luke Skywalker"/>

            <p><a href="http://rottenonions.freeforums.org/who-needs-a-200x200-av-t106-50.html">Luke For Prez</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Penguins R Us</h2>
            <img class="center" src="img/penguinImageSet/penguin.png" alt="Cartoon Penguin"/>

            <p><a href="http://www.zonadiyer.com.ar/post72281.html">Penguins</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>BioHazard</h2>
            <img class="center" src="img/bioImageSet/bio.gif" alt="Biohazard Symbol"/>

            <p><a href="http://www.instructables.com/file/FEJMEETFGHSZ9J9/">BioHazard</a></p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Row -->


    <footer id="footy">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="legal">
                    <hr>
                    <p id="copy">&copy;2015 Denver Coder</p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div> <!-- Container -->

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Framework Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <div id="logo" class="col-6"><img src="img/denvercoderlogo.png" alt="Denver Coder Logo with Denver Skyline and Mountains"/></div>
        <div id="name" class="col-6"><h1>Timothy Myers</h1><h3>Denver COder</h3></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="mainImage" class="row">
        <img src="img/mainImage.jpg" alt="Desk with laptop and some supplies"/>
    </div>
    <div id="features" class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h2 class="featured">Featured Work</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="project-images" class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><img class="center" src="img/darthnevets.png" alt="Stylized Luke Skywalker"/></div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="center" src="img/penguin.png" alt="Cartoon Penguin"/></div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="center" src="img/bio.gif" alt="Biohazard Symbol"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="titles" class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Luke For President</div>
        <div class="col-4">Penguins R Us</div>
        <div class="col-4">BioHazard</div>
    </div>
    <div id="urls" class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><a href="http://rottenonions.freeforums.org/who-needs-a-200x200-av-t106-50.html">Luke For
            Prez</a></div>
        <div class="col-4"><a href="http://www.zonadiyer.com.ar/post72281.html">Penguins</a></div>
        <div class="col-4"><a href="http://www.instructables.com/file/FEJMEETFGHSZ9J9/">BioHazard</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer id="footy">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="legal">
                <hr>
                <p id="copy">&copy;2015 Denver Coder</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

my problem is the mainImage is not centering regardless of what I try. I don't know if I have implemented the srcset improperly or not but the other images on the site are fine.

I have turned on borders and you can see how the main image is off to the left.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then post your question. By the way, give `text-align: center;` to `.row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like in the following CSS code for centering images and contents within `.row`

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also you can try `class="img-responsive center-block"`.
Just add it for all your images like so:

```
<img src="img/mainImageSet/mainImageMedium.jpg" alt="Desk with laptop and some supplies" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

Comment: But Op suggested his page link from there I found that code.

Comment: oh thank you for your suggestion. next time i will be carefull.

Answer (score 1):

Add `class 'center'` to the `div` just above the `picture` like this:

```
<div class="row center">
    <picture class="center">
        <source srcset="img/mainImageSet/mainImageLarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)"></source>
        <img alt="Desk with laptop and some supplies" src="img/mainImageSet/mainImageMedium.jpg">
    </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: I answered the question after checking the HTML of the page whose link DenverCoder shared with us.

Comment: I just figured that anyone knowledgeable enough to help would be able to go to the page and click "View Page Source" and then click on the css file to view it. It just seemed like the best solution because then you could test your solution right in the browser. Again sorry I will post the code next time.

Comment: For a place where people come for help there sure are a lot of uptight people. Look at my rep, 11, probably means I don't post here often.